# Rails: Join is not joining the results of another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am trying to execute the following Statement in Rails. The statment works and returns the correct results

```
SELECT  * from exports JOIN viewviewerimages ON exports.ImageID = viewviewerimages.ImageID
```

ViewViewerImages and exports table have already been create on an mssql database. I have tried the following executions

```
 Export.joins('JOIN viewviewerimages ON exports.ImageID = viewviewerimages.ImageID').all
 #Returns just the export table 

 ViewiewerImage.joins('JOIN viewviewerimages ON exports.ImageID = viewviewerimages.ImageID').all
 #returns viewerImageTable
```

Now I want to be able to access a variable so I assign the statements

```
JoinedVariable = ViewiewerImage.join(...JOIN...)
print JoinedVariable.ViewerImageVariable # '1325'
print JoinedVariable.ExportVariable #'nil'
```

Is there anything wrong with the above steps?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. 
Due to the fact that the model for Export was mistyping the the UUID. 
I made sure to generate a new model and migrate a new table over to confirm. 
The join worked with a few test cases.